# Mismatch in result for matrix exponential calculation using Python and Mathematica

Tags: python, wolfram-mathematica, taylor-series

I wrote the simple python code for evaluating matrix exponential using truncated Taylor series given by the [formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fC8yL.png), where M is the matrix, t is time and k is the order of truncation, which isn't converging to correct values even for large orders. I wrote the same code in Mathematica, which is converging correctly. I am not able to find the error in the python code due to which it is producing incorrect result.

The **Python code** is-

```
def matrix_exponential_taylor(m, t, order):
    result = np.eye(m.shape[0])
    for i in range(1,order+1):
        term=np.linalg.matrix_power(m*t,i)/np.math.factorial(i)
        result+=term.astype(np.float64)
    return result
```

```
A = np.array([[2, 1, 0, 1],
               [1, 1, 1, 0],
               [0, 1, 3, 1],
               [1, 0, -1, 2]])
t = 3
order = 1000
result = matrix_exponential_taylor(A, t, order)
print(result)
```

output from Python code-

```
[[3594.20250036  1511.17187957 -1249.84655916  3085.96687505]
[5087.48182172  2074.0643393    769.10695263  4399.3840113 ]
[7966.0379292   4335.76396246  1637.40121583  7160.40223197]
[ -480.68704288 -1249.84655916 -3584.7820205  -1947.37752023]]
```

**Mathematica Code**-

```
MatrixExponentialTaylor[m_, t_, order_] := 
Module[{result, term}, result = IdentityMatrix[Length[m]];
For[i = 1, i < order, i++, term = MatrixPower[m*t, i]/Factorial[i];
result += term;];
result]
```

```
m = {{2, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 3, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 2}}
t = 3;
order = 1000;
result = N[MatrixExponentialTaylor[m, t, order]]
result // MatrixForm
```

output from Mathematica code-

```
{
  {6110.33, 1480.1, -4384.45, 3441.73},
  {10249., 4630.23, -942.716, 8307.71},
  {17076.6, 7826.18, -1178.47, 14172.3},
  {-5327.16, -4384.45, -5403.36, -6581.83}
 }
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. I get different results when I run your posted python code, and they almost match your claimed  mathematica result...

Comment: @Julien Yes, you are right. Weirdly, on my system, it's giving the above result only, while in other systems, it's giving the result that almost matches the Mathematica result. I tried restarting the kernel and changing the environment and system restart. But, still can't figure out why it's wrong on my system, but correct in other systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get faster and closer results by updating your term at every iteration rather than recomputing it from 0:

```
def matrix_exponential_taylor(m, t, order):
    term = np.eye(m.shape[0])
    result = np.eye(m.shape[0])
    mt = m*t
    for i in range(1,1+order):
        term = term @ mt / i
        result += term
    return result
```